# How to position input fields below a dynamically growing table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a parent div that contains a child table at the top and below it a set of input fields.

The table has a given top/left positioning and it's hight is dynamic.

```
.table-panel {
 position: absolute;
 top: 30px;
}
```

The input fields too have pre-assigned top/left  values that are calculated based on a fixed table height.

```
.one {
  top: 300px;
  left: 0;
}

.two {
  top: 350px;
  left: 0;
}
```

Problem is, if the actual table height is greater than the original fixed height, the table and input fields overlap when rendered. Sample fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/c2Lztzfd/142/

I have the freedom to readjust the top/left positioning of the fields but have to abide to the exact gap between the fields. Therefore use of flex layout does not work.

As a solution i was looking at readjuting the original input field postioning so they shift down by a x no of pixels. Where x is the difference between the actual table height and the original height.

Is there a better way to tackle this maybe using css positioning (absolute/relative) for example..?

Comment: Well you can check table height and set field top equal to that height plus how much you need...

Comment: if you fix the top of `.one` and `.two` and also you position them to `absolute`, how do you expect them to *move down* as the table grows?

Comment: Yes, that's an option. Was wondering if there is a different/better way say using css positioning (absolute/relative) for instance.

Comment: @Scaramouche Grows in the way she doesn't want to change top position every time she add new fields. But if she want to use position absolute she can do what I posted as answer by getting table height and changing fields positions. Right?

Comment: @Scaramouche it's not a must to use position absolute. The top of .one and .two i do have the freedom to recalculate.

Answer (score 1):

You have given `absolute` position to the fields. Move them inside the div containing the table and make the position relative. That way they will be relative to the table and below it.

Check out https://jsfiddle.net/c2Lztzfd/150/

Comment: This would work but the original top positioning applied on the fields would result in https://jsfiddle.net/c2Lztzfd/156/. Unless somehow i recalculate the top positions..

Comment: Since you want to position the fields below the table, you will need to reduce the top to 20 and 30.  https://jsfiddle.net/c2Lztzfd/156/

Comment: yes, that's the tricky bit. I'm required to keep the same gap between the fields when reducing the top values. So original values 300 px and 350 px with a field height is 30 px would require a gap of 20 px between the 2 fields. And the gap can vary between diferent fields. Hence i cannot randomly reduce to top values..

Answer (score 1):

Look, all I just did was commenting out every bit of css code that was getting in your way to achieve what you asked. Now, it's up to you to figure out if you can get away with removing those parts or you are not in the liberty to do so. Basically it's about `absolute` positioning and setting the `top` property to fixed values; if you can get rid of that, then you should be set.

LMK

```js
$('#add').click(function(){
  $('tbody').append($('tbody').children('tr').last().clone());
});
```

```css
div.parent {
   position: relative;
   width: 500px;
   /*height: 400px;*/
   border: 3px solid green; 
}

.table-panel {
 /*position: absolute;*/
 top: 30px;
}

div.field {
    /*position: absolute;*/
    width: 105px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}

.one {
  /*top: 300px;*/
  left: 0;
}

.two {
  /*top: 350px;*/
  left: 0;
}


/* table Styling */
#customers {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    /* border-collapse: collapse; */
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

#customers td, #customers th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#customers th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="table-panel">
    <table id="customers">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Company</th>
          <th>Contact</th>
          <th>Country</th>
        </tr>  
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
          <td>Maria Anders</td>
          <td>Germany</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
          <td>Christina Berglund</td>
          <td>Sweden</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
          <td>Christina Berglund</td>
          <td>Sweden</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr> 
         <tr>
          <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
          <td>Christina Berglund</td>
          <td>Sweden</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr> 
      </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
    <div class="field one">absolute Field 1</div>
    <div class="field two">absolute Field 2</div>
    <button id="add">add</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't said without jquery, I added some example how you can do it.

Even for more fields than 2.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var $table = $('#customers');
  
  var $fields = $('.field');
  
  for(var i=0; i<$fields.length; i++) {
    var top = + $table.height() + ((i+1) * 50);
    $fields.eq(i).css('top', top+'px');
  }

});
```

```css
div.parent {
   position: relative;
   width: 500px;
   height: 400px;
   border: 3px solid green; 
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

.table-panel {
 position: absolute;
 top: 30px;
}

div.field {
    position: absolute;
    width: 105px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}

.one {
  top: 300px;
  left: 0;
}

.two {
  top: 350px;
  left: 0;
}


/* table Styling */
#customers {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    /* border-collapse: collapse; */
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

#customers td, #customers th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#customers th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="table-panel">
    <table id="customers">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Company</th>
          <th>Contact</th>
          <th>Country</th>
        </tr>  
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
          <td>Maria Anders</td>
          <td>Germany</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
          <td>Christina Berglund</td>
          <td>Sweden</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
          <td>Christina Berglund</td>
          <td>Sweden</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr> 
         <tr>
          <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
          <td>Christina Berglund</td>
          <td>Sweden</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr> 
      </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
    <div class="field one">absolute Field 1</div>
    <div class="field two">absolute Field 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is exactly the effect you wanted but you can do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Afro523/c2Lztzfd/152/ Changed the hierarchy and your CSS a little to make the sticky effect work.  I don't know your requirements so I thought a pure CSS solution might float your boat.  If not I like the jQuery answer.

**Index.html**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="table-panel">
    <table id="customers">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Company</th>
          <th>Contact</th>
          <th>Country</th>
        </tr>  
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
          <td>Maria Anders</td>
          <td>Germany</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
          <td>Christina Berglund</td>
          <td>Sweden</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
          <td>Christina Berglund</td>
          <td>Sweden</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr> 
         <tr>
          <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
          <td>Christina Berglund</td>
          <td>Sweden</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr> 
      </tbody>
   </table>
       <div class="field one">absolute Field 1</div>
  </div>
    <div class="field two">absolute Field 2</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.field {
    position: sticky;
    width: 105px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}

.one {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.two {
  top: 350px;
  left: 0;
}
```